# How to self generate certificate SHA-256?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, signature, sha256, makecert

I use [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) libraries in C# to sign with [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), and I'd like to use them in a test of a self generated certificate instead of a smartcard reader.

Using the self certificate used before, I have a cryptographic exception:

> specified algoritm not valid

If I use a [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) signature with the same self certificate, it goes well. With the smartcard the same code run successfully.

What is the makecert parameter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 4.5 version of makecert supports other signing algorithms such as sha256, sha384, or sha512. See [makecert 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (-a)

Comment: I used multiple version of Command Line because of multiple Visual Studio versions. I used the VS 2012 command line.

Answer (score 2):

There is no parameter for makecert to use SHA256 has a hashing algorithm for makecert.exe. You can only use `-a md5` or `-a sha1`.

Note there are also issues with certificates using a SHA256/384/512 hash on Windows XP and Windows 2003 and earlier operating systems (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/01/23/sha-2-support-on-windows-xp.aspx) and this may be what you are seeing.